# Where Can I Download Import Image As Plane Add-On For v2.7?

Tags: add-on, import

I'm using Blender v2.7 (other program requires that version) and I need the Import Image As Plane, but I can't find the add-on for Blender v2.7.  Where can I download the Import Image As Plane add-on for Blender 2.7?

Answer (score 1):

The [Addons](https://developer.blender.org/project/view/3/) project links to the [Addons Catalog](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts)([archive](https://archive.blender.org/wiki/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/)) which gives a list of all the 2.6 scripts where you can get the details for [Image as Planes](https://archive.blender.org/wiki/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Add_Mesh/Planes_from_Images/) which then links to the SVN repository containing the actual [Python script](https://svn.blender.org/svnroot/bf-extensions/trunk/py/scripts/addons/io_import_images_as_planes.py).

And hopefully that is in a usable state.